# What is simplest way to add domain name to a Debian server?

Tags: apache, debian

I have the latest brand new Debian server. The website should host only 1 single domain name.
DNS are resolved by the registrar and A points to my dedicated server. Site is present in `/var/www/`.

What is the simplest way (step by step) to configure Apache to add this domain name?

Answer (score 0):

It should be very straighforward:

1. Install Apache (`sudo aptitude install apache2`)
2. The default configuration points to /var/www so...
3. Start Apache (`sudo service apache2 restart`)
4. Enjoy your website
5. You can add your domain name into `/etc/hosts`
6. Take some steps to secure your dedicated server (iptables, fail2ban, ...)

You could also use the automatic wizard with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure apache2`.

I think this should be enough if you DNS is already pointing at your IP.

If you really need to change the configuration file, it's in `etc/apache2/sites-available/default` and contains the following (by default):

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost  # <= Email of webadmin (shown on error pages)

DocumentRoot /var/www/           # <= Root of your web server with public access
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None       # <= Disable usage of .htaccess files
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    # This directive allows us to have apache2's default start page
            # in /apache2-default/, but still have / go to the right place
            #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
ServerSignature On

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

As for the hosts file, you can add the following:

```
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost

#Virtual Hosts 
12.34.56.789    example.com #<= change here :)
```

Then, don't forget to secure your web server with appropriate tools (iptables, fail2ban, ...)